# Scheduling callback with virtual function in constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, lambda

As Scott Meyers wisely taught us in Effective C++ (3rd ed.):

> Item 9: Never call virtual functions during
> construction or destruction.

Now, consider the following piece of code:

```cpp
class my_class
{

  my_class()
  {
    // here we _cannot_ call other_virtual()

    // but will this lambda call the correct function
    // if it is called after this CTOR has exited its scope?
    schedule_work([this]{ other_virtual(); });
  }

  void schedule_work(std::function<void()> callback);
  virtual void other_virtual() = 0;
}

class derived : public my_class
{
  derived() : my_class() {}
  
  // make sure to implement the pure virtual
  void other_virtual() override;
}
```

So is this reliable C++? Will this work according to the standard?

Comment: Yes, this will work.

Comment: in your code you never actually call the virtual method, so there isnt something that could fail

Comment: fwiw, the reason you cannot call it in the constructor of `my_class` is that it is pure virtual in `my_class`. Scots advice is more general though

Comment: As I write in the code assume that the scheduled function will be called somewhere else later on in the code.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, Thanks, but I'm aware of that point. I was just curious whether there would be any compiler function call resolution that would make the wrong virtual function be called - pure or not.

Comment: what is `schedule_work` ?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - Will work because when the callback is run, it will have a complete vtable and thus the proper callback resolution will occur?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, A function that schedules are callback.

Comment: where do you call the lambda?

Comment: This is not valid if the implementation of `schedule_work` decides to immediately invoke the `callback` for any reason (for example: if the function decides that the work is somehow overdue or urgent and needs to be done immediately.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was just curious whether there would be any compiler function call resolution that would make the wrong virtual function be called - pure or not.

There is no virtual dispatch in the constructor. If you call `other_virtual` in the constructor of `my_class`, then `my_class::other_virtual` is called, no matter what the dynamic type of the object under construction actually is. Thats why Scott recommends to avoid calling virtual methods in a constructor in general, it works (unless the method is pure virtual), but it might surprise.

Outside of the constructor (and outside of the destructor) there is virtual dispatch and if you call `other_virtual` on an object whose dynamic type is `derived` then `derived::other_virtual` will be called.

Comment: *"Outside of the constructor"* and destructor.

Comment: You say, _There is no virtual dispatch in the constructor._ But how do you know that `schedule_work` is guaranteed not to invoke its `callback` immediately upon being called?  The implementation was not given.  The implementation of `schedule_work` could just be `{ callback(); }` (perhaps gated behind an `if` or something.) You're making an assumption based on the name of the function I think.

Comment: @Wyck you are completely right. I tried to ask for clarification from OP, just that sometimes I dont follow the right order of things, and now that my answer is accepted, I cannot delete it anymore. Anyhow, I think the answer does not make any assumptions. It merely states that if the call to the method happens inside or outside the constructor it will make use / not make use of virtual dispatch, respectively

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, I see from your comments that you're seeking clarification on the matter, that's good, thanks!  :)

Answer (score 0):

This will work because when the callback is run, it will have a complete vtable (in most compilers, even though the standard does not specify vtables) and thus the proper callback resolution will occur.

This vtable is not guaranteed to be completed in the CTOR, so it cannot be called directly there.

Comment: the vtable is an implementation detail and not that relevant here. If the method would be virtual but not pure virtual, then one could call it in `my_class` constructor, it would work without any vtable being involved

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, not true. See https://www.aristeia.com/EC3E/3E_item9.pdf

Comment: "The last line of
the Transaction constructor calls the virtual function logTransaction, but
this is where the surprise comes in. The version of logTransaction that’s
called is the one in Transaction, not the one in BuyTransaction — even
though the type of object being created is BuyTransaction." Thats exactly what I am saying

Comment: You're right that it is callable and will call the present class's function, but this is probably not intended most of the time.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, I think we agree, but missed each others point. You talked about what would happen technically, but I was meaning the surprising unintended call to the present class' virtual.

Comment: well, you write "... so it cannot be called directly there." But the reason you cannot call it, is that its pure, not just that it is virtual. Of course what you refer to is probably the reason why it is specified like this, but your last sentence follows the common misunderstanding (that scotts advice tries to avoid). You can call it (when it is not pure virtual), and it will do the right thing (whether this is what you expect is another question)